# Customizing Date Serialization in Axios

Tags: javascript, typescript, axios, interceptor, utc

By default, when a JavaScript object contains a Date object, Axios serializes it into UTC. This means that the time transmitted is converted using the time zone. This doesn't work for my use case. I need to send the time without the time zone conversion to UTC.

I implemented a custom serializer based on [#1548](https://github.com/axios/axios/issues/1548), but it has no effect. I have verified that the config is being modified, but when I look at the request payload, the dates are still using UTC (2022-02-03T04:59:00.000Z).

Note: My logic is more complicated, I am using toLocalString() in the code below to simplify the example.

```
const a = axios.create()
a.interceptors.request.use((config) => {
  config.paramsSerializer = (params) =>
    qs.stringify(params, {
      serializeDate: (date: Date) => date.toLocaleString(),
    })
  return config
})
```

Anyone understand why I can't override the default behavior and use my own date formatting?

Environment
Axios Version 0.21.1

Comment: If you need user timezone information, I find it best to send the date (instant) as either a timestamp or ISO 8601 UTC date string as well as the user timezone, eg `{ date: "2022-01-12T00:00:00.000Z", tz: "America/New_York" }`

Comment: Ya, but that wasn't the question.

Comment: That's why it's a comment and not an answer

Answer (score 24, accepted):

It's not Axios doing the serialisation. `Date` implements [toJSON()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/toJSON) which is employed when your objects (containing dates) are serialised via [JSON.stringify()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify#description)...

> The instances of `Date` implement the `toJSON()` function by returning a string (the same as `date.toISOString()`). Thus, they are treated as strings.

The `paramSerializer` is for serialising **query** params which is why it didn't apply to your request body.

To transform the request body, you want to use `transformRequest`.

Here's a generic, recursive transformer that finds dates and maps them to localised strings

```js
import axios, { AxiosRequestTransformer } from "axios"

const dateTransformer: AxiosRequestTransformer = data => {
  if (data instanceof Date) {
    // do your specific formatting here
    return data.toLocaleString()
  }
  if (Array.isArray(data)) {
    return data.map(val => dateTransformer(val))
  }
  if (typeof data === "object" && data !== null) {
    return Object.fromEntries(Object.entries(data).map(([ key, val ]) =>
      [ key, dateTransformer(val) ]))
  }
  return data
}
```

You can then register this transformer in your Axios instance which will apply to all PUT, POST, PATCH and DELETE requests.

```js
const instance = axios.create({
  transformRequest: [ dateTransformer ].concat(axios.defaults.transformRequest)
})

instance.post(url, data)
```

---

If the generic version seems a little heavy-handed, you can either transform the object yourself before posting...

```js
const body = {
  date: new Date()
}

axios.post(url, {
  ...body,
  date: body.date.toLocaleString()
})
```

or register an inline transformer

```js
axios.post(url, body, {
  transformRequest: [
    data => ({
      ...data,
      date: data.date.toLocaleString()
    }),
    ...axios.defaults.transformRequest
  ]
})
```

Comment: Very helpful. Thank you for the time you put into the detailed answer.

Comment: Realy good answer, how it works with FormData?

Comment: Right now I'm just checking if it's an instance of FormData, otherwise, in some cases, it doesn't work.

Comment: @PrimulaX you'd be better off just appending the appropriately formatted string into your `FormData` instance.

Comment: @Phil Don't know, I think I am doing it the right way:
`formData.append('id',id);`
`formData.append("photo", file);`
that way.

Comment: @PrimulaX sorry but what does that have to do with date formatting?

Comment: @Phil Sorry might I have missed something, what do you mean by the appropriately formatted string? It's just an id and the file.

Comment: @PrimulaX you're asking on a post about formatting dates in Axios request payloads

Comment: @Phil Okay, I won't ask

Answer (score 3):

This is Phil's most excellent answer with small modifications for typescript. This is for axios 0.21.1. (In version 0.23.1+ it looks like `AxiosTransformer` was refactors to  `AxiosRequestTransformer`)

```
const dateTransformer = (data: any): any => {
  if (data instanceof Date) {
    // do your specific formatting here
    return data.toLocaleString()
  }
  if (Array.isArray(data)) {
    return data.map(dateTransformer)
  }
  if (typeof data === 'object' && data !== null) {
    return Object.fromEntries(Object.entries(data).map(([key, value]) => [key, dateTransformer(value)]))
  }
  return data
}
const axiosInstance = axios.create({
  transformRequest: [dateTransformer, ...(axios.defaults.transformRequest as AxiosTransformer[])],
})
```

Comment: FYI if you had tagged your question with [tag:typescript], you would have received a Typescript answer

Comment: Makes sense. I wasn't complaining. You answer was fantastic, but I'll keep that in mind for future reference.

Comment: @CindyConway I disagree with phil. I think adding a 2nd answer makes it such that the same question does not to be asked again for the context of TypeScript.

Answer (score -1):

```
    const replacer = function(this: any, key: string, value: any) {
        if (this[key] instanceof Date) {
           return moment(this[key]).format("YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss")
        }    
        return value
    }
    
    const axiosInstance = axios.create({
      transformRequest: [(data, headers) => JSON.stringify(data, replacer), ...(axios.defaults.transformRequest as AxiosRequestTransformer[])]
    })
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).